# E-mail Regexp accepting www

Tags: regex

I have a field for e-mail and confirm email and they are accepting www. which must not

here is my regexp

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

;

any ideas?

Comment: Why shouldn't it accept www?  `www.` is just part of a domain name, and there's nothing invalid about it in an email address, though it is uncommonly used.

Comment: Do you mean "the regexp accepts the string 'www', which it should not"?

Comment: The string "www" doesn't even appear in your regex. What makes you think it would exclude "www"?

Comment: @ michael yes  but i have no choice clients forced me.. @bergi correct

Comment: It does not accept the string "www": http://regexr.com?3115k

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
 ^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+(?<!@www)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

this matches

```
test@test.com
```

but does not match

```
test@www.test.com
```

The difference is the negative lookbehind introduced at the end

```
(?<!@www)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

maxlength 128